# Is it possible to change the installation directory using OneGet?

Tags: package-management, windows-packagemanagement

I'm trying to install an app, for example Firefox using:

```
Install-Package -Name Firefox -Source chocolatey
```

But by default it installs on `C:\Program Files`. I would like instead make it install on `D:\Program Files`.

Is there a way to change the installation directory?

Comment: This whole thread is an answer to this question: https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/95
(Not sure how to summarize this into a "proper" answer, so a comment will do.)